# Word for "the best example of a contrast to this" (i.e. opposite of epitome)?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Google gives this example for "epitome":

> "she looked the epitome of elegance and good taste"

I'm wondering whether there's an opposite word, to mean "the best example of the opposite/contrast of.." e.g.

> "she looked the ____ of elegance and good taste"

Meaning she was an example or demonstration of the complete opposite to elegance and good taste.

Comment: "Counterexample", perhaps?

Comment: *Antiepitome* sounds like a good candidate.

Comment: @Drew Is it a word?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It is now, if you want it to be. ;-)

Comment: @Drew In my view, it's a misuse of 'word' if less than a reasonable number of speakers of the language involved understand the candidate and use it reasonably freely. And no, I can't legislate for what a 'reasonable number' is, but DIY 'words' don't qualify (at least immediately).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It was a joke. I didn't submit it as an answer. But feel free to use it anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Antithesis***

Merriam Webster (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antithesis)

"the exact opposite of something or someone

the state of two things that are directly opposite to each other"

Example (made up): "After an eight hour overnight plane trip in economy class, I felt wrinkled and weary, and my hair was a mess; I was the antithesis of the woman I wanted to be at the upcoming business meeting."

Comment: I was about to close-vote on general reference grounds. Then I checked the thesauruses available.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: What did you see?

Comment: @justhalf The two I checked missed 'antithesis'.

Comment: @mirror318 Thanks for the green tick!

Answer (score 2):

***[Antipode](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/antipodes):***

> - (used with a sing. or pl. verb) Something that is the exact opposite or contrary of another.

From [The works](https://books.google.it/books?id=VdscAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA352&lpg=PA352&dq=the%20antipode%20of%20elegance&source=bl&ots=fTuDlIhRhV&sig=KiRY2YMxLqvsevaHW1pxbj-2IXs&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4-rb39aTJAhWEcA8KHYs4AQ8Q6AEIKzAE#v=onepage&q=the%20antipode%20of%20elegance&f=false) of Samuel Taylor Coleridge:

> - But the proper *antipode of a gentleman*  is to be sought for among the Anglo-American democrats.

Answer (score 1):

I like the two answers given already, especially 'antithesis', but would also offer up:

Nadir

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nadir

"The worst or lowest point of something"

In some (not all) cases I think it's a better fit.

eg: "she looked [like] the nadir of elegance and good taste"